# SQL showing the results of two queries

Tags: sql

I have two tables. Customers and Employees and I want a query that displays all customers and employees who live in California.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: This is very basic stuff in sql. Better read a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the UNION https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp. Be aware that when SELECT-ing both have to have selected the same amount of columns.